# object and cursor moving in opposite directions

Tags: objects, 3d-cursor, object-mode

I am an absolute beginner with Blender. I have a weird problem for which I can't find a solution: when I grab, the object moves in the opposite direction with respect to the cursor. If I press the left arrow, the cursor goes on the left, the object moves to the right and viceversa.

Added registration of the desktop (origins on):
https://streamable.com/zakfp3

As I say above, cursor moves one way, object in the opposite direction

Default settings:
https://streamable.com/jjunbq

Here the cursor moves, the object is stuck

Comment: you mean for example with the default cube? without any modifier or constraint?

Comment: And what if you move the mouse, without pressing arrows? Could you give a specific list of what you do? For example: I select an object with LMB, I press G once, I move the mouse. So we can try to reproduce the problem and find a solution. Thanks :-)

Comment: @moonboots default cube, everything is at default. The weird thing is that I tried on another laptop and it doesn't happen

Comment: @mugnozzo with the mouse it's the same thing. Sequence of actions: select the cube, g, press arrow (move mouse). 

Let me know any information you need

Comment: It's very strange. Did you try with a new scene and with more than one object? Does it always do de same? On which Operating System are you running Blender and which version of Blender are you running? Did you try to reinstall it? Sorry for the many questions but I hope I (or somebody else) can help you. More infos, more possibility to help.

Comment: @mugnozzo Yes, same thing with multiple objects. OS is Ubuntu 20.04, Blender 2.83.5. Re-installed multiple times, tried to load factory defaults, but nothing has worked.

Comment: Ok. That's strange... I guess it can be something related to the OS, but I don't know. I also tried to search for similar problems reported by others, but I don't find anything. :-(

Comment: I added the video of what happens...

Comment: It really looks like that is a problem with drivers on GPU. It's noticeable that the direction of the movement in in +Y axis (Y axis orientation is shown on the gizmo) which correlates with the operator info (viewport top left, it says it's moving Dy 0,7m) but the cube is moving in -Y. What happens if you release mouse to confirm? What GPU do you run Blender on?

Comment: @MrZak If I release, the position is confirmed for both cursor and the object. The GPU is a nvidia gtx 1660Ti

Comment: This is not exactly the usual default setting. The colored axis seem to match with the one when "affect only origin" is on. Do you know why?

Comment: @lemon Checked again, you're right. I have activated "origins" because otherwise it doesn't even move. Resetted to factory defaults again, I'm going to upload a new video.

Comment: I have tried on Windows by the way, there it works perfectly. I'm starting to think it's the nvidia driver on linux somehow.

Comment: @VittorioApicella, I'm doubtful about the GPU driver, as this seems to be software only: I mean the cursor moves, the origin moves, but the mesh is moved opposite. How can that be the gpu? .... Even if this is not occuring on all your computers, could you upload the file?

Comment: @lemon I uploaded the registration of what happens with totally default settings. About the software...I tried to reinstall multiple times, but nothing has ever changed

Comment: @VittorioApicella, you have used 2.90.0 this time. But have you tried to use factory settings or use the setting from a computer where there is no issue?